# my one plus two no longer be able to connect to computer

Tags: oneplus-two

I have tried the suggestions posted previously, but nothing works.  For example, the USB tethering is grayed out and no matter how i press or slide, it still show no USB connected.  I used to have a choice of either charging or file transfer, but not anymore after I upgrade the phone software.  Please help.

Comment: Since the problem has started soon after you've upgraded the software, you should contact the phone manufacturer, because this seems to be a bug in the update. You should inform them of the bug. Till then, you can use [TeamViewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile) on your phone and computer to transfer files wirelessly. Download the desktop version, and connect your phone following on-screen instructions.